# Order data by name instead of default json/ c#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

So I've got a webpage that displays some product data. The data is called in form of a json object in the javascript file :

```
_loadAll: function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        'type': 'GET',
        'timeout': 5000,
        'cache': false,
        'dataType': 'json',
        'url': Application.ProductURL + 'Series/Load/All',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response && callback) {
                callback(response);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, errorText, errorCode) {
        }
    });
}
```

(Note: I took the project over from somebody else so just sorting through it figuring out how it works)

I've located the ProductURL which looks like this in c# :

```
 public Stream LoadProduct(string productNumber)
        {
            var product = new JSONObjects.JProduct(productNumber);

        return SerializationHelper.Streamify(product);
        }

        public Stream LoadAllSeries()   
        {
            IProductSeriesCollection series = new ProductSeriesCollection();
            series.LoadAll();


            return SerializationHelper.Streamify(series);
        }
```

The JSONObjects.JProduct I've located in another cs file:

```
  public class JProduct: IProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SeriesId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

public void Load(string productNumber)
    {
        _product = new ProductProxy(productNumber);

        Id = _product.Id;
        SeriesId = _product.SeriesId;
        Name = _product.Name;
}
```

So my actual question: The products are currently displayed sorted by their ID which is the default ,I guess. However, I need them to be sorted by Name. I assume I can't do this within the javascript file? I haven't worked with jsons before so not sure. Any suggestions on how to sort it by Name are appreciated!

Comment: I guess you should take a look in `ProductSeriesCollection.LoadAll()`.

Comment: Try applying `.OrderBy` linq expression over LoadAll()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in this sort of code you can sort at any of about 3 levels:

1) In the data source (e.g. SQL server), especially if you're using LinqToSQL or EntityFrameworks.

2) At the server side after loading the data.

3) At the client side in Javascript.

Generally I will try to do the sorting as close to the data as possible, and only sort at the client side when I absolutely have to do so.  There are numerous opportunities to sort before it gets that far.

The data layer code you've inherited doesn't look like it's all that well implemented, but check out how the `ProductSeriesCollection.LoadAll` method works, because that's where you'll probably want to apply sorting.  At worst you'll need to know how the `ProductSeriesCollection` functions in order to sort the contents after `LoadAll` has been called.

Seriously though, I strongly suggest that you look into a L2S or EF replacement for your current data layer.  Then you can just tack an `OrderBy()` clause on your query and be done with it.

---

Since you can't change the order at the server, you can use the `Array.sort` method to modify the sequence of the objects at the client side.

First, define a comparison method that will return -1, 0 or 1 depending on the order you want the compared items to be placed in.  For instance:

```
function compareProduct(a, b) {
    if (a.Name < b.Name)
        return -1;
    if (a.Name > b.Name)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Or if you like compact code that isn't quite so readable:

```
function cmpProduct(a,b) { return a.Name < b.Name ? -1 : a.Name > b.Name ? 1 : 0; }
```

Your AJAX call then uses that to sort the received array before passing it to the callback.  If the response is an array:

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response && callback) {
        callback(response.sort(compareProduct));
    }
},
```

If not directly an array, find the array of products and call sort on it.

Comment: Yeah I know it's not ideal but I need to keep it like it is for now until I can convince the owners to change things more thouroughly. Another issue is that the data layer code also affects other parts of the website so ideally I'd sort it in the Javascript

Comment: In that case, the `Array.sort` method is probably what you need.  Will update.